# Black screen after grub or at reboot with LUKS encryption

Tags: boot, grub2, luks

I know this subject was already treated, and I found a "fix" to bypass this black screen thanks to this answer (LUKS encyption part): [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)

So, if when the black screen appears, I just press Alt + ← and then Alt + → to switch my tty, I have now the password asking screen for the decryption.

It's cool, I can now boot ! But what can I do to fix this problem definitively ?

**EDIT: THIS TRICK DOESN'T WORKS:** *When grub is loaded (it's not at each boot, sometimes that display directly the black screen), I can edit the grub entry via the 'e' key and add to the "linux..." line the "readon.modeset=0" command. With this, it works again and I can access the password asking screen.*

So if you have a solution to fix this problem definitively, I'll happy to read it.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I made a mistake: the workaround with grub doesn't work (modeset=0 or nomodeset), however I don't need to do Alt + → and alt + ← when i'm facing the black screen, a simple Left or Right are enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can change your /etc/default/grub settings to include modeset. 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

then update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1631395

Comment: I just edit my post. This trick doesn't work, I just made a mistake when I test this. Sorry for that and thank you for your answer.